# Convert array into object with custom key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array:

```
let Given = [
  ["SRM_SaaS_ES,MXASSETInterface,AddChange,EN"],
  ["ASSETNUM,AS_SITEID,apple,ball"],
  ["mesa01,SDASITE,ball,cat"],
  ["ASSETNUM,AS_SITEID,cat,ager"]
];
```

What i want is get the first array as keys and the rest as its respective values as follows:

```
let needed = [{
    'SRM_SaaS_ES': 'ASSETNUM',
    'MXASSETInterface': 'AS_SITEID',
    'AddChange': 'apple',
    'EN': 'ball',
  },
  {
    'SRM_SaaS_ES': 'mesa01',
    'MXASSETInterface': 'SDASITE',
    'AddChange': 'ball',
    'EN': 'cat',
  },
  {
    'SRM_SaaS_ES': 'ASSETNUM',
    'MXASSETInterface': 'AS_SITEID',
    'AddChange': 'cat',
    'EN': 'ager',
  }
]
```

What i tried to do was get the first array and then assign the values to the first array as keys but i couldn't.

```
let firstArrayData: string = this.Given[0];
let data = firstArrayData[0].split(',');
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));//["SRM_SaaS_ES","MXASSETInterface","AddChange","EN"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
let Given = [
  ["SRM_SaaS_ES,MXASSETInterface,AddChange,EN"],
  ["ASSETNUM,AS_SITEID,apple,ball"],
  ["mesa01,SDASITE,ball,cat"],
  ["ASSETNUM,AS_SITEID,cat,ager"]
];

// first get the keys out of the first sub array:
const keys = Given[0][0].split(",");

// then map over the rest of the sub arrays:
const result = Given.slice(1).map(function(item) {
  // get values from current item
  const values = item[0].split(",");
  // create an object with key names and item values:
  const obj = {};
  keys.forEach(function(k,i) {
    obj[k] = values[i];
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Beat me by 1 min. :-)

Comment: thank you. I am quite noob to javascript inbuilt functions. Thanks for the thorough explanation as well.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this can be done in several ways; I just posted the first way that came to mind. I didn't put links to any doco in my answer, but there is [an MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) about arrays with links to explanations of all the build-in array methods. Also a tip on looking up functions: if you are trying to google a function that you see in somebody else's code add "mdn" to your search terms (so "map mdn" if looking for the `.map()` method), and the first google result should be the relevant MDN page.